# Решить задачу про асинхроность

Tags: javascript

Задача про асинхроность

Есть такой класс asyncArray

```
const _async = (fn, cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => cb(fn()), 100);
};

const asyncArray = function(a = []) {
    if(!new.target) {
        return new asyncArray(a);
    }

    this._read = (index, cb) => 
        _async(() => a[index], cb);
    
    this._size = (cb) => {
        _async(() => a.lenght, cb);
    }
        
};
```

Нужно привести asyncArray к обычному линейному массив.
В asyncArray могут встречаться как числа, так и asyncArray, так же значения приходят через какой-то промежуток времени.

```
const asArray = asyncArray([1, 2, 
                            asyncArray([3, 4]),
                            5]);
const result = solve(asArray);
//result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Функция solve() что-то сделает с asArray.
Как понять что значения пришли если read или size вызываются через какой-то интервал, он может быть случайным. В примере 100мс.
Вопрос как? Я не понимаю, что только не пробовал.

Comment: непонятно, что значит _привести объект такого массива к обычному линейному массиву_

Comment: Я что-то не очень понял `asyncArray` - это же класс, как он должен возвращать массив? Может в `asyncArray` есть ещё методы, которые вы не показали? Если в нынешнем виде просто вызвать `asyncArray`, то на выходе мы просто получим экземпляр класса `asyncArray`, с 2-мя методами, но точно не массив. А ещё я нигде не вижу, в какой момент данные приходят асинхронно, все начальные значения устанавливаются сразу, вот методы `read` и `size` будут работать синхронно

Comment: пока еще не стало понятнее. В текущем коде ничто не мешает вызывать так как ты хочешь

Comment: в таком виде - никак.

Comment: А что можно изменить чтобы было это возможно, может промисы или что-то ещё

Comment: Promise, либо как тут уже используются -коллбэки, которые вызываются когда функция выполнилась